# Maximize marks obtained

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is a n*n matrix given.

The row denotes the student and the corresponding column denotes marks obtained in that particular paper.

for example->

```
n=3

1 2 3 

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

Then 1st student scores 1 in 1st paper, 2 in 2nd paper and so on.

2nd student scores 4 in 1st paper, 5 in 2nd paper and so on.

**given->Every student will get only one exam paper to solve**

We need to maximize total marks obtained by n students following above condition.

for above input, output->>(8+6+1)=15.

constraints->

1<=n<=100

```
My approach->

I thought to solve it using dp+bitmask but n can be as large as 100 so had to drop this idea.
```

Comment: Does the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical [weighted bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs) problem, and can be solved using [KM algorithm (Hungarian algorithm)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

To construct the bipartite, we put all students in one set, and all exam papers in the other set. We connect a student to an exam paper with an edge of value `X`, where `X` is the score that student can gain in that exam. After the graph is constructed, just run KM algorithm and you will get the answer.

Here is a [tutorial from top coder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=hungarianAlgorithm) which explains this kind of problem quite well, and a code template is also given. You can start from here :)